# Convert topographic map to vector and text

Tags: attribute-table, text, vectorization

I have a topographic map in TIFF format and I vectorized it in QGIS (3.22.0). For my project I needed the settlements, which I was able to extract. More importantly are the names of the settlement. These are vectorized, however the are not recognized as texts but as polygons. Is there a way to convert them into texts, and moreover, is it possible to have all the settlement names be added as an attribute in the attribute table?

Comment: What GIS software do you have available? look into OCR https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition it has improved with assistance from generative AI.

Comment: QGIS 3.22.0. I dont have any other OCR-Software on my PC

Comment: there are lots of OCR online converters. some are using AI capabilities to improve results.

Comment: I have used these - And i get quite good results, but i cannot display them back in qgis